# Sourcetree, Mercurial and creating a debug branch

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been trying to find actual documentation for Sourcetree without much luck, so I figured I'd ask here.  I'm a relative newb when it comes to version control, with my current project being my first effort.  I'm using Sourcetree on Windows 7 as a frontend for Mercurial, I've got my development code on my local machine in C:\inetpub, and whenever I do a Commit I then switch Sourcetree over to the cloned repository on my backed up network drive and do a Pull of the changes I just Committed so I've got the development history backed up.

What I'm trying to wrap my head around is using Sourcetree to set up a Debug branch so I can fix bugs on the version of the code running on the production server while simultaneously doing development.  Obviously a common need, but I can't grok it.  I am expecting there to be two code locations, so I can pause in mid-edit on the Development branch, make changes to Debug, and them come back to my changes in Development and finish them up before merging in the changes to Debug.  If that's not how it works that's presumably part of my confusion.  Any suggestions on where I can find clarity?  Pointers to existing tutorials and the like would be fine, I just haven't been having luck searching Google, and I haven't been able to locate any actual Sourcetree documentation.

NOTE:  Based on responses I've seen to other questions I've read about Sourcetree and Mercurial, I'll state upfront I have no interest in discussing outside repository hosting unless somebody can explain why it will help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

1. You do not need to change repository to pull, you can also push from your local repository;
2. You do not need 2 code locations for switching from one branch to the other. It might help, for larger projects, but I suggest you get comfortable with Mercurial before doing so.

So, for number 1, there is a default source or remote repository for every local repo. It is either defined by the user or it is the source repo from where it was cloned. Whether you push or pull, it will default to that same source. You can push/pull to multiple sources as well, but this is not your case at the moment. In the normal workflow, just issue a ***hg push*** every time you commit, and your changes will be propagated to the other repo.

For number 2, a Mercurial repo, as you already know, can have multiple branches. When you commit a changeset, it is automatically done on the current branch. In SourceTree, click on the Branch button, and enter a new branch name. The next commit you'll do will be the head (and the start) of your new branch. After that, you can update back and forth between the 2 branches, and your code will change accordingly. That means that you can update at any time to the head of any branch, make some changes, commit, and then jump to another branch, and so on. So no, you do not need multiple repositories.

Normally, the proper practice is to have a **default** branch (default name is rarely changed!) where you have your current development source. For every issue or feature you are fixing/implementing, create a new branch from the default branch to put your new code. Once that branch has been reviewed and tested, merge it back in the default and close the former.

For your current development, if you need an additional stable and safe trunk, you can create a **Production** branch, which would be the stable code that will run on your server. Once you are satisfied with the default branch tests, you can then merge it in Production to include your changes up to that point.

As a convention, make sure your server is always running the code from the **Production** branch, for the more stable code. At least, that is what I understood from your initial question.

Comment: As far as point 1 in concerned, I kind of assumed that it should be possible to push, but I started pulling, and since changing between repositories is just a matter of switching which tab I'm on it isn't a big deal.

Comment: As for the rest, here's the scenario that I can't comprehend without two repositories:  I am working on code changes in example.php in  the **default** repository, and a bug report comes in on the live version of the same file.  I open the **debug** branch version of example.php, fix the bug, commit that change to **debug**, and upload the **debug** instance of example.php to the live server.  I then finish up the work I was doing in the **default** version, commit the changes to **default**, and then pull the changes from **debug**.  

How do I do that with just one repository?

Comment: Just to clarify, the part that confuses me about that scenario is that there's only one instance of example.php on my local server, so there can't be two simultaneous editable versions.

Comment: As I said before, if you are comfortable with working with multiple repos, this is a completely valid workflow. One repo you will have a new changeset in the **debug** branch, and in the other one, a new changeset on **default**. Just remember to synchronize both repos, too, by pushing/pulling. Working with a single repo implies to commit your current changes as a **default** commit, update to **debug** branch, commit, then re-update on **default** for continuing the development. Difference is that you have only one repo to sync, and maybe less error-prone.

Comment: Synchronizing 2 repos with a single common source implies to push both repos on the common repo, then pulling back again.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get there, but I'm still a touch confused by your comment "synchronizing 2 repos with a common source".  What is the "common source"?  I'm more or less thinking in terms of treating the **default** branch as holding the equivalent of v1.1 while **debug** holds v1.0.x, with my live server running a copy of v1.0.x until I update it to v1.1.  In that case **default** is the primary repo, into which I'll push any changes I make in **debug**, but I don't think that's what you mean by "synchronizing 2 repos with a single common source".  Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, thank you for sticking with me, I'm finding your comments very helpful.

Comment: No problem! Is your server an external system? If it is, it means it also has a copy of the repo? You then have 2 local copies and one remote. When you have only 2 repos total, synchronizing is easy, every push/pull from one to the other replicates the full repo on both places. If you have 3 repos, A must sync with B, and then sync with C. And if C also had changes, you sync again. Complexity increases exponentially, until you decide that one repo becomes the common... For your current setup, why not use the server's repo!

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean.  Because of the way I think I probably will go with the 2 locals 1 remote setup, but I recognize your concerns.  Thanks for helping me think this through.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if you need more information.